# Android (HTC M8) has "forgotten" my SD Card is encrypted. Help!

Tags: encryption, photos, htc-one-m8

Having a bit of a stressful problem. My HTC m8 (Marshmallow) is encrypted, as well as the external SD card. All my photos are on the SD card. I have lots backed up but I'm having a great trip to NYC that didn't backup to google because I was roaming (it seems). Anyway, today my phone crashed (I think the battery is failing, it turned off instantly at 14%). When it turned on, all my photos are showing a gray icon (like they are corrupted). I cannot imagine how every single photo (of thousands) in multiple folders has corrupted.

Now, I noticed that when I go into Storage options the "Encrypt SD Card" box is UNTICKED. Implying the phone has forgotten the card is encrypted and thus cannot read the images. Though I thought it was weird that it can read the directories at all, implying its doing a file by file encryption rather than a full card encryption.

Anyway, obviously I know my PIN number that I need to decrypt the phone at boot up, is there any tool I can use to decrypt the images using this PIN? My fear is that (upon some research) that this is "encFS" encryption, which uses an encfs6.xml file to read the data and consequently the crash has deleted/corrupted this file. If so, this seems like a very delicate encryption mechanism.

Something else, when the phone started up again, it had reset a few other things. My default keyboard was no longer SwiftKey, I'm getting Android "tips" for scrolling etc... Does android back that file up anywhere? Does stock android call the file encfs6.xml?

Anyway, please, anyone, help me get my photos back :(

Many Thanks